# Can I autowire named loggers?

Tags: java, spring, logging, autowired

I'm using non static loggers named according to class name:

```
protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
```

Can I configure spring in a way, that will set proper logger using @Autowired?

```
@Autowired
protected Logger logger;
```

I can use factory-method for logger initialization, but I don't know how to pass the class name as an argument. For the setter-based dependency injection, spring has to know the class name, since it holds the reference to the bean. Can I access it somehow? Is there another way?

Comment: Is there another purpose behind this?

Comment: I'm just curious whether spring can handle logger dependencies in a more convenient way (like lombok does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inject it with @Inject and BeanFactoryPostProcessor

```
@Inject
Logger logger;
```

You can find more details here: [Using java annotation to inject logger dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351082/using-java-annotation-to-inject-logger-dependency)

Comment: I think that this is the correct answer. I have used spring's post processors for something else recently and from the backward perspective it is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 20):

In order to make Logger be injectable with `@Autowired`, you must have a configuration class where you have configured all the Beans with which you use `@Autowired`. That class will be marked with `@Configuration`. There you must put the following `@Bean` in your configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Logger produceLogger(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        Class<?> classOnWired = injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass();
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(classOnWired);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer.  Asking nicely......it is so much easier to figure these out when the java examples contain all the important import statements listed, without "*".

Comment: For future readers: import org.springframework.beans.factory.InjectionPoint;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a `@Qualifier` annotation.  Of course that means that you have added `Logger` objects to your application context already.

Importing this config into your application context would allow you to do that:

```
@Configuration
public class LoggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Logger myClassLogger() {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public Logger myOtherClassLogger() {
        return LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyOtherClass.class);
    }
}
```

And then in your classes that uses the `Logger`:

```
@Component
public class MyClass {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myClassLogger")
    private Logger logger;

    //...
}

@Component
public class MyOtherClass {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myOtherClassLogger")
    private Logger logger;

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to use autowired logger as describe below:

```
package de.senatov.wflow.config;

import org.slf4j.Logger;

@Configuration
public class WebFlowConfig extends AbstractFacesFlowConfiguration {


    @Autowired
    private Logger log;



    @Bean
    public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {

        log.debug("flowRegistry()");
        return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder(flowBuilderServices()).addFlowLocation("/WEB-INF/flows/booking/booking-flow.xml", "booking")
                                                                      .addFlowLocation("/WEB-INF/flows/main/main-flow.xml", "main").build();
    }
.....
....
```

1) insert small class:

```
package de.senatov.wflow.loggable;


import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InjectionPoint;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;

import static java.util.Optional.of;
import static org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger;

@Configuration
public class LoggingConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Logger logger(InjectionPoint ip) {

        try {
            return getLogger(of(ip.getMember())
                                     .map(o -> o.getDeclaringClass())
                                     .orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.printf("slf4j autowired Exception occured : %s%n", e.getMessage());
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```