# Using Java annotation to create a Logger in class

Tags: java, logging

Is it possible to create annotation to expose a custom Logger variable into the class for direct use, so that I don't have to do something to the effect of:

`Logger logger = CustomerLoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);`

It would be nice if the above was implicitly available due to the annotation and I could just go about doing logger.debug("..."); without the declaration.

Similar question is asked `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6351082/using-java-annotation-to-inject-logger-dependency` for Spring and all answers are Spring specific. I am looking for simple Java.

Edit: I cannot use lombok as the IBM product I am developing for provides its own logger factories and those the only way to get a logger via `MXLogger.getLogger(key) method`

Comment: What about using Lombok? https://projectlombok.org/features/log

Comment: There was a lombok solution in the link you gave.

Comment: _In general_, this isn't possible. As noted above, this _specific_ modification is supported by Lombok (through some rather unorthodox and non-generalizable techniques).

Comment: This is what I am looking for. How is lombok doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Add maven Lombok dependency and user @log4j2
2. Create a class that will return logger to you

If I understand you correctly, this is ur answer.

Comment: Lombok can only provide some specific loggers I believe. The IBM product I am developing for gives logger from its own factory.